# Schedule sending messages to consumers at different rate

Tags: algorithm, optimization, scheduling

I'm looking for best algorithm for message schedule. What I mean with message schedule is a way to send a messages on the bus when we have many consumers at different rate.

Example : 
Suppose that we have data D1 to Dn
 . D1 to send to many consumer C1 every 5ms, C2 every 19ms, C3 every 30ms, Cn every Rn ms
 . Dn to send to C1 every 10ms, C2 every 31ms , Cn every 50ms

What is best algorithm which schedule this actions with the best performance (CPU, Memory, IO)?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I can think of quite a few options, each with their own costs and benefits. It really comes down to exactly what your needs are -- what really defines "best" for you. I've pseudocoded a couple possibilities below to hopefully help you get started.

Option 1: Execute the following every time unit (in your example, millisecond)

```
func callEachMs
    time = getCurrentTime()
    for each datum
        for each customer
            if time % datum.customer.rate == 0
                sendMsg()
```

This has the advantage of requiring no consistently stored memory -- you just check at each time unit whether your should be sending a message. This can also deal with messages that weren't sent at `time == 0` -- just store the time the message was initially sent modulo the rate, and replace the conditional with `if time % datum.customer.rate == data.customer.firstMsgTimeMod`.

A downside to this method is it is completely reliant on always being called at a rate of 1 ms. If there's lag caused by another process on a CPU and it misses a cycle, you may miss sending a message altogether (as opposed to sending it a little late).

Option 2: Maintain a list of lists of tuples, where each entry represents the tasks that need to be done at that millisecond. Make your list at least as long as the longest rate divided by the time unit (if your longest rate is 50 ms and you're going by ms, your list must be at least 50 long). When you start your program, place the first time a message will be sent into the queue. And then each time you send a message, update the next time you'll send it in that list.

```
func buildList(&list)
    for each datum
        for each customer
            if list.size < datum.customer.rate
                list.resize(datum.customer.rate+1)
            list[customer.rate].push_back(tuple(datum.name, customer.name))

func callEachMs(&list)
    for each (datum.name, customer.name) in list[0]
        sendMsg()
        list[customer.rate].push_back((datum.name, customer.name))
    list.pop_front()
    list.push_back(empty list)
```

This has the advantage of avoiding the many unnecessary modulus calculations option 1 required. However, that comes with the cost of increased memory usage. This implementation would also not be efficient if there's a large disparity in the rate of your various messages (although you could modify this to deal with algorithms with longer rates more efficiently). And it still has to be called every millisecond.

Finally, you'll have to think very carefully about what data structure you use, as this will make a huge difference in its efficiency. Because you pop from the front and push from the back at every iteration, and the list is a fixed size, you may want to implement a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) to avoid unneeded moving of values. For the lists of tuples, since they're only ever iterated over (random access isn't needed), and there are frequent additions, a singly-linked list may be your best solution.

.

Obviously, there are many more ways that you could do this, but hopefully, these ideas can get you started. Also, keep in mind that the nature of the system you're running this on could have a strong effect on which method works better, or whether you want to do something else entirely. For example, both methods require that they can be reliably called at a certain rate. I also haven't described parallellized implementations, which may be the best option if your application supports them.

Comment: I think first proposition is so limited because it is exponential complexicity. So when number of Data/consumer increases performance degrade considerably. From my side I have coded the second one (preparing schedule table before sending) but with some optimization that I shared in the next answer. The problem is also when number of consumer increases with very different rate, the schedule table grows.

Comment: How does the first proposition grow with exponential complexity? I'm pretty sure it's O(mn) worst case for m datums and n customers. And as I said, the primary purpose for the first version is using as little memory as possible, which could be useful for embedded systems. You weren't super clear about what the application was ("best performance (CPU, Memory, IO)" is pretty ambiguous), so I tried to give multiple options for different priorities.

Comment: yes it was a mistake, I will fix it the complexity is O(nm) (linear complexity).

Answer (score 0):

Like Helium_1s2 described, there is a second way which based on what I called a schedule table and this is what I used now but this solution has its limits.

Suppose that we have one data to send and two consumer C1 and C2 :
[image: simulation with three different couple rates]

Like you can see we must extract our schedule table and we must identify the repeating transmission cycle and the value of IDLE MINIMUM PERIOD. In fact, it is useless to loop on the smallest peace of time ex 1ms or 1ns or 1mn or 1h (depending on the case) BUT it is not always the best period and we can optimize this loop as follows.

for example one (C1 at 6 and C2 at 9), we remark that there is cycle which repeats from 0 to 18. with a minimal difference of two consecutive send event equal to 3. 
so :

```
HCF(6,9) = 3 = IDLE MINIMUM PERIOD
LCM(6,9) = 18 = transmission cycle length
LCM/HCF = 6 = size of our schedule table
```

And the schedule table is :

[image]

and the sending loop looks like :

```
while(1) {
  sleep(IDLE_MINIMUM_PERIOD); // free CPU for idle min period
  i++; // initialized at 0
  send(ScheduleTable[i]);
  if (i == sizeof(ScheduleTable)) i=0;
}
```

The problem with this method is that this array will grows if LCM grows which is the case if we have bad combination like with rate = prime number, etc.

Comment: The memory usage of this solution is going to become really problematic, especially if any of your rates are prime numbers. You should look into implementing a circular buffer instead, since the memory usage in that case is simply the length of the longest rate divided by the greatest common factor. And the circular buffer means you still have O(1) random access, so you won't have time efficiency problems.

Comment: For example, say you have things published at the rates 5, 7, 15, and 25. That's an LCM of 525 and a GCF of 1. So your queue will be 525 long. Whereas a circular buffer would only be 25 long.

Comment: Yes taking an array (circular buffer or other) of max rate size and calculate the next index of next event slot  is a great solution in some case but there is some other situation where the memory used by Circular buffer solution will take a large memory like if we have (real example about geolocation) 200ms, 1000ms and 1 hour (3600 kms) with circular buffer you must have a size of 3600.000 long but 18000 with other. And when number of data grows each solutions reaches they limits. I think there is another way because this kind of problem exists in many domains and sure there is other solution

Comment: From my comment above, "You should look into implementing a circular buffer instead, since the memory usage in that case is simply the length of the longest rate divided by the greatest common factor." In fact, the memory used by the circular buffer will always be less than or equal to the amount used by the LCM/GCF solution.

Comment: In the example you give, the GCF is 200, the LCM is 3600000, and the maximum value is 3600000. So the circular buffer would use max/GCF=3600000/200=18000 memory, and your method would use LCM/GCF=3600000/200=18000 memory. In this case, the LCM is equal to the max value, so the methods use the same amount of memory.